# Is there any way to access a Symfony secret value in userland code?

Tags: php, symfony

Despite making them appear to be environment variables, Symfony does not actually load secrets into the environment, so you can't access them via getenv() or $_ENV. Is there any way to access them other than via DI? I'm trying to have the secret name be stored as an entity property in a database, then have a service class read the appropriate secret's value for whichever entity is requested by the API client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add your env values to your parameters in `config/services.yaml` like that (you can even have them be booleans, JSON or whatever) :

```yaml
parameters:
    your_secret: '%env(YOUR_SECRET)%'
    your_bool: '%env(bool:YOUR_BOOL)%'
    your_json: '%env(json:YOUR_JSON)%'
```

Then you can, for example, retrieve it from a controller like so:

```php
    $yourSecret = $this->getParameter('your_secret');
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing... I meant to come back and answer my own question, but forgot. You get the credit instead.

Answer (score 2):

In production, secrets:decrypt-to-local is [recommended for performance reasons](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/secrets.html#deploy-secrets-to-production). This creates .env.prod.local and the secrets are then available in $_ENV.

When deploying, I use:

```
php bin/console secrets:decrypt-to-local --force --env=prod
```

Locally, instead of using dev secrets, I keep the values in .env.local

Comment: How would you then access these values in a controller extending Abstract Controller? I have this kind of deployment but getting "variable not defined" error

Comment: They can be accessed using $_ENV. For example in .env.local:
FOO=bar

and in a controller action:
dd($_ENV['FOO']);